# how to hover a pointer-events:none / another way to solve this mystery

Tags: html, css, hover, pointer-events

I have 4 elements on top of each other, with the following opacity settings (from bottom to top):

1. id - 0
2. id - 0
3. div - 1
4. text - 1

I need that by hover element 2, the changes of the opacity settings will be:

1. id - 1
2. id - doesn't matter
3. div - 1
4. text - 0

Because element 2 is my trigger, I need both elements 3+4 to be `pointer-events:none` , so the hover will affect element 2 (that is under them).

I believe the reason both of these elements don't change is that `pointer-events:none` . am i correct?

```
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(234, 255, 248);
  justify-content: center;
}


#background {
  position: absolute;
  background-color:rgb(255, 125, 125);
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#animation {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(25, 138, 0);
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.squares {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: purple;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.A {
  color: aliceblue;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.squares:hover ~ #background {
  opacity: 1;
}

.squares:hover ~ #animation {
  opacity: 1;
}

.squares:hover ~ .text {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
<body>

<div class="c">
  <div class="squares">
    <div class="A">13</div>
     </div>

  <div id="background">11</div>

  <div id="animation">11</div>

          <div class="text">
            PARTICIPATE TO VIEW IMGS
          </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The 4 elements from bottom to top seem to be .squares, #background, #animation, .text but this is not what your question describes as that has the second element as the one to be hovered. Please could you clarify? And no, pointer-events: none is not the reason things aren't changing on the hover of .squares.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the reason for not changing the elements was the `pointer-events:none` CSS you used.
As a workaround you could try using the div with `class="c"` which wraps all `position:absolute` elements as the trigger.
CSS needs to be changed as follows

```css
.c:hover #background {
  opacity: 1;
}

.c:hover #animation {
  opacity: 1;
}

.c:hover .text {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Also you may need to add `display:grid` or `display:flex` to the `body` CSS to center the elements using `justify-content:center`

Comment: pointer-events: none isn't going to affect whether the styling of an element can change.